# Gitlab CI can't connect to service / No HOST or PORT found

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to run an integration test against my containers on gitlab.

To keep things as minimal as possible, here are the relevant parts of my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: ubuntu:latest

coverage:
    stage: test
    dependencies:
        - build
    services:
        - postgres:latest
        - registry.gitlab.com/username/project/image:latest
```

When I try and run the job, I get a container health check warning.

`2019-06-06T02:13:34.508595817Z FATAL: No HOST or PORT found`

Normally I would start my image with the standard `docker run -p port:port image:version` but I'm not sure how those options translate to gitlab services. How do I define the host and the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example pipeline connecting to postgres.

The container aliases the service as the container name, unless you explicitly alias as shown [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#servicesalias)

```
services:
- name: postgres:9.4


variables:
  # Configure postgres service (https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)
  POSTGRES_DB: $DB_NAME
  POSTGRES_USER: $DB_USER
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $DB_PASS

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/*

stages:
  - test
  - build


db-test:
  stage: test
  image: ubuntu:latest
  tags:
    - consultancy
    - shared
  script:
    #set server connection env vars
  - export PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  - apt-get update -y && apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib -y
  - psql -h "postgres" -U "$POSTGRES_USER" -d "$POSTGRES_DB" -c "SELECT 'OK' AS status;" #ensure the service is running

node-test:
  stage: test
  image: node:latest
  tags:
  - consultancy
  - shared
  script:
    - npm install # Install Node dependencies
    - npm run test-unit # Execute unit testing suite
#
integration-tests:
  stage: test
  image: node:latest
  tags:
  - consultancy
  - shared
  script:
  - export PGUSER=$POSTGRES_USER
  - export PGHOST=postgres
  - export PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  - export PGDATABASE=postgres
  - export PGPORT=5432 #set the integration test env vars
  - npm install # Install Node dependencies
  - npm run test-integration # Execute integration testing suite
```

Comment: I appreciate your response and I believe it to be the correct answer. I'd like to add that my specific issue was I was assuming the image name to be the same whether I was using a public registry or the gitlab private registry. I had to define an `alias` to get my image to use the hostname without a huge prepended registry path.

Answer (score 9):

in my case, Dockerfile without `EXPOSE`, will give the wrong log msg in ci runner:

```
Health check error:
exit code 1

Health check container logs:
2020-05-12T03:42:49.645731131Z No HOST or PORT
```

fixed by expose service port in Dockerfile.

Comment: How do you expose it in the GitLab CI config? The normal docker command for my entermediadb container needs port 8080 but I don't know how to set or expose it. I have no own Dockerfile.